# Mixin Pattern and prototype constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've heard about [mixin pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) yesterday, and I'm trying it but I'm confused with what I think is a basic concept.

Let's focus on this function :

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
```

On the base constructor prototype iterations, one of the property name is `constructor`. So what we do is reassign the derivedClass prototype constructor to the last baseClass prototype constructor.

Let's say we have three class :

```
class Disposable {
  public isDisposed: boolean;
  public dispose() {
    this.isDisposed = true;
  }
}

class Activable {
  public isActive: boolean;
  public activate() {
    this.isActive = true;
  }
  public deactivate(){
    this.isActive = false;
  }
}

class MyDisposableObject implements Disposable, Activable {
  //Disposable
  public isDisposed = false;
  public dispose: () => void;

  //Activable
  public isActive = false;
  public activate:() => void;
  public deactivate:() => void;
}
```

After `applyMixins(MyDisposableObject, [Disposable, Activable])` we no longer have the right constructor on MyDisposableObject instances.

```
const m = new MyDisposableObject();
console.log(m.constructor); // output : f Activable() {}
console.log(m instanceof MyDisposableObject) //output : true !?
```

- According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), **The constructor property returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object.** which is not the case anymore because `applyMixins` reassign the derivedClass.prototype.constructor. Can't this lead to side-effect ?

```js
var Disposable = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Disposable() {
    }
    Disposable.prototype.dispose = function () {
        this.isDisposed = true;
    };
    return Disposable;
}());
var Activable = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Activable() {
    }
    Activable.prototype.activate = function () {
        this.isActive = true;
    };
    Activable.prototype.deactivate = function () {
        this.isActive = false;
    };
    return Activable;
}());
var MyDisposableObject = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyDisposableObject() {
        //Disposable
        this.isDisposed = false;
        //Activable
        this.isActive = false;
    }
    return MyDisposableObject;
}());
applyMixins(MyDisposableObject, [Disposable, Activable]);
function applyMixins(derived, bases) {
    bases.forEach(function (base) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(base.prototype).forEach(function (name) {
            derived.prototype[name] = base.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
var m = new MyDisposableObject();
console.log('m constructor :', m.constructor);
console.log('m instanceof MyDisposableObject : ', m instanceof MyDisposableObject);
```

### **EDIT :**

I still don't understand why the documentation example reassign the constructor of **derivedClass.prototype** and if this is harmful or not so while I wait for a great explanation, I modified the applyMixins to ignore constructor property :

```
function applyMixins(derived, bases) {
  bases.forEach((base) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(base.prototype)
    .filter((name) => name.toLowerCase() !== 'constructor')
    .forEach((name) => {
      derived.prototype[name] = base.prototype[name];
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Not sure why `constructor` appears as activatable (FYI in edge it does not so have fun with that) but you migh be better off with this pattern for mixins: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I ran the code in Edge but I have the same result. I executed `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Activable.prototype)` and `constructor` is the first element of the array returned. I'll check your link

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir there's a slight difference between this implementation and the one described in the doc. The purpose here is to compose (`implements`) instead of using classic inheritance (`extends`). The `customer` object created is of type `Customer` but also of type `Person`. If I understood correctly, mixin pattern doesn't require a class to have a parent, this implementation require the custom class to extend Tagged class.